# Derive the representation of a vector field in a parametrization of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Here is one question I'm trying to figure out:

Let $w$ be a vector field in an open subset $U$ of a regular surface(cf. the book by do Carmo) $S$ and let $\mathbb{x}:V\to U$ be a parametrization of $S$. Show that $w$ can be written as
$$w(\mathbb{x}(u,v))=f(u,v)\mathbb{x}_u(u,v)+g(u,v)\mathbb{x}_v(u,v).$$
$\color{red}{-------------------------------------}$

I have obtained a result that seems to benefit this problem: Let $p\in U$ and let $\mathbb{x}^{-1}(p)=q$. Since $w(p)$ is a tangent vector to $S$ at $p$, there is a differentiable parametrized curve $\mathbb{x}(a(t),b(t))$ with $\mathbb{x}(a(0),b(0))=p$ such that $w(p)=\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{x}(a(t),b(t))\vert_{t=0}$. By the chain rule, one can see
$$w(p)=a'(0)\mathbb{x}_u(q)+b'(0)\mathbb{x}_v(q).$$
Can anyone please tell me what else I should do to finalize the proof(written in the language of mathematics)? Thanks.

Comment: How do you define a vector field on a regular surface? (I'm asking because my definition is, more or less, something that looks like the expression you are trying to prove).

Comment: I adopt the definition by do Carmo. A vector field $w$ in $U$ is a mapping that assigns to each $p$ in $U$ a tangent vector $w(p)$ to $S$ at $p$.

Comment: OK, so at every point, you have two numbers satisfying the equality you wrote. This is the same as saying you have two functions, $f$, and $g$, like you want.

Comment: Intuitively, I'm fine with your explanation. Actually, that's what I came up with in the beginning. But I don't think it's a "proof".

Comment: Thanks. I decided to move on. Maybe someday I'll pick it up.